# Merge consecutive delivery date (with certain condition) into one merge ID in R

Tags: r

So I was looking to merge consecutive dates into one merge ID (grouped by SHIP_TO). But, if the consecutive date is longer than 3 days, the merge id will be different too. Here are the following code that I used

```
dhl_mutate <- dhl %>%
  arrange(SHIP_TO) %>%
  group_by(MERGE_ID= cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(DELIVERY_DATE) > 1))) %>%
  ungroup()
```

here are the following output that I got

| SHIP_TO | DELIVERY_DATE | MERGE_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2006 | 2021-04-01 | 1 |
| 2006 | 2021-04-02 | 1 |
| 2006 | 2021-04-03 | 1 |
| 2006 | 2021-04-04 | 1 |
| 2006 | 2021-04-19 | 2 |
| 2006 | 2021-04-23 | 3 |
| 2006 | 2021-04-27 | 4 |
| 2010 | 2021-06-01 | 5 |
| 2010 | 2021-06-02 | 5 |
| 2010 | 2021-07-05 | 6 |
| 2010 | 2021-04-07 | 7 |

My expected output is that for every three consecutive dates, the system will generate a new merge id and the new delivery date will be the same for the last date within the same merge ID

| SHIP_TO | DELIVERY_DATE | MERGE_ID | NEW_DELIVERY_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2006 | 2021-04-01 | 1 | 2021-04-03 |
| 2006 | 2021-04-02 | 1 | 2021-04-03 |
| 2006 | 2021-04-03 | 1 | 2021-04-03 |
| 2006 | 2021-04-04 | 2 | 2021-04-04 |
| 2006 | 2021-04-19 | 3 | 2021-04-19 |
| 2006 | 2021-04-23 | 4 | 2021-04-23 |
| 2006 | 2021-04-27 | 5 | 2021-04-27 |
| 2010 | 2021-06-01 | 6 | 2021-06-02 |
| 2010 | 2021-06-02 | 6 | 2021-06-02 |
| 2010 | 2021-07-05 | 7 | 2021-07-05 |
| 2010 | 2021-04-07 | 8 | 2021-04-07 |

I would be extremely grateful if someone could help me with this, thank you!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you also add a minimal part of your data set? You can do so using the function  `dput`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach using `ceiling_date` from `lubridate` -

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df <- df %>%
  mutate(DELIVERY_DATE = as.Date(DELIVERY_DATE), 
         NEW_DELIVERY_DATE = ceiling_date(DELIVERY_DATE, '3 days'), 
         MERGE_ID = match(NEW_DELIVERY_DATE, unique(NEW_DELIVERY_DATE))) %>%
  group_by(MERGE_ID) %>%
  mutate(NEW_DELIVERY_DATE = max(DELIVERY_DATE)) %>%
  ungroup

df

#   SHIP_TO DELIVERY_DATE MERGE_ID NEW_DELIVERY_DATE
#     <int> <date>           <int> <date>           
# 1    2006 2021-04-01           1 2021-04-03       
# 2    2006 2021-04-02           1 2021-04-03       
# 3    2006 2021-04-03           1 2021-04-03       
# 4    2006 2021-04-04           2 2021-04-04       
# 5    2006 2021-04-19           3 2021-04-19       
# 6    2006 2021-04-23           4 2021-04-23       
# 7    2006 2021-04-27           5 2021-04-27       
# 8    2010 2021-06-01           6 2021-06-02       
# 9    2010 2021-06-02           6 2021-06-02       
#10    2010 2021-07-05           7 2021-07-05       
#11    2010 2021-04-07           8 2021-04-07
```

`ceiling_date` rounds the date up every 3 days, using `match` and `unique` we get a unique `MERGE_ID` and for each `MERGE_ID` we select the `max` `DELIVERY_DATE`.

**data**

It is easier to help if you provide data in a [reproducible format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

```
df <- structure(list(SHIP_TO = c(2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 
2006L, 2006L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L), DELIVERY_DATE = c("2021-04-01", 
"2021-04-02", "2021-04-03", "2021-04-04", "2021-04-19", "2021-04-23", 
"2021-04-27", "2021-06-01", "2021-06-02", "2021-07-05", "2021-04-07"
), MERGE_ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 7L)), 
row.names = c(NA, -11L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the suggestion! But the syntax above will classify merge id based on its date. Meanwhile, the expected output is that the merge id is classified based on date as well as ship_to (1 merge id for 1 ship_to and 1/2/3 delivery date). what should I do?

Comment: Maybe try adding `SHIP_TO` in `group_by` i.e `group_by(SHIP_TO , MERGE_ID)`